# Error installing BPEL plugins of WSO2 on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, wso2, bpel

I need to install WSO2 from the Eclipse Marketplace. When I go to do the installation, everything seems to be proceeding in the right direction but, at some point, in the plugins summary, it comes out that these two plugins will not be installed:
Business Process Server Artifacts
Business Process Server BPEL Tools
The error is this:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Business Process Server Artifact 3.8.0 (org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.bpel.artifact.feature.feature.group 3.8.0)
  Missing requirement: EMF Model for ODE Deployment Descriptor 1.0.4 (org.eclipse.bpel.apache.ode.deploy.model 1.0.4) requires 'osgi.bundle; javax.wsdl [1.5.0,1.6.2]' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: UI for ODE Deployment Descriptor 1.0.4 (org.eclipse.bpel.apache.ode.deploy.ui 1.0.4)
    To: osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.bpel.apache.ode.deploy.model 1.0.1
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: BPEL 3.8.0 (org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.artifact.bpel 3.8.0)
    To: osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.bpel.apache.ode.deploy.ui 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Business Process Server Artifact 3.8.0 (org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.bpel.artifact.feature.feature.group 3.8.0)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.artifact.bpel [3.8.0,3.8.0]
```

I necessarily need to be able to run BPEL because of a thesis project. How can I go about solving it?